# How to unique sum in a column with unique keys and sequence values

Tags: pandas, group-by, analysis

Here is my data-frame something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'shipment_name':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C','C','C'],
        'city_name':[2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,9],
        'volume':[46,46,46,46,46,50,50,50,50,50,50,55,55,55,55,55],
        'customer_name':['James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James']
    })
```

I want a code that gives me an answer with values such that:
Between The Cities 2-3, total volume flowing is (46+50 = 96) and the total volume flowing between cities 5-6 is (46+50+55 = 151). For customer named James, his shipment volume carried is 151 in between 5 and 6 , 96 between 2 and 3.

I did not understand how to code it.

I did not understand how to code it.**strong text**

Comment: I do't really understand what you're asking.  Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Check my question again. I have updated it

Comment: You made your question *less* readable by including a link to an image, and you didn't actually change the content of the question.  Also review [ask].

Comment: Did you find the question and data correct now?

Comment: Give me a moment. I am new to this place., I will change it properly now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the difference, mean, sum between all pairs of rows in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227593/how-to-find-the-difference-mean-sum-between-all-pairs-of-rows-in-pandas-datafr)

Answer (score 0):

Please take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These will help you gather helpful responses more quickly.

IIUC, this code should assist you in framing your question:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'shipment_name':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C','C','C'],
        'city_name':[2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,9],
        'volume':[46,46,46,46,46,50,50,50,50,50,50,55,55,55,55,55],
        'customer_name':['James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James','James']
    })
u = df.groupby(['city_name']).sum()
```

To give you:

```
           volume
city_name        
1              50
2              96
3              96
4              96
5             151
6             151
7              55
8              55
9              55
```

You can then create the combinations by following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227593/how-to-find-the-difference-mean-sum-between-all-pairs-of-rows-in-pandas-datafr). I've done some simple combination below:

```
u = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(u.volume, u.volume)), u.city_name, u.city_name)
stacked = u.stack()
stacked = pd.DataFrame({'cities': stacked.index.to_series(), 'diff': stacked})[['cities', 'diff']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Please read the `.groupby()` documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

Comment: Module object Dataframe is not callable, it says

Comment: are you calling `import pandas as pd` at the beginning of your code?

Comment: I believe that the error you're seeing is a distinct question from the one you've posted. I would recommend searching StackOverflow for a solution. If nothing helps, then I would post a separate question to try and find a resolution to that issue.

Comment: I will properly phrase it and ask the question again